# result from Await DisplayAlert Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

**Xamarin** has awaitable `DisplayAlert` method which returns `Task<bool>`.

I have `static` class `Helpers` where i want to write code like this:

```
public static bool DisplayAlert(string title, string message, string accept, string cancel){
    //return answer from Page.DisplayAlert(title, message, accept, cancel);
}
```

This method will be called from other parts of the app like:

```
public ... SomeMethod(){
    // some code
    bool result = DisplayAlert(...);
    // some code
}
```

I want to avoid `async/await` in `SomeMethod`. (How you can wait a response from a user asynchronously?!!!!!!)

I tried  `await Page.DisplayAlert(...)`, `task.Wait()` and another. But `Task` was executed asynchronously with no return value. Or application freezes forever without displaying `DisplayAlert`.

How to do it? What's the best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `SomeMethod` to remain Synchronous, this is one option:

```
public async static Task<bool> DisplayAlert(string title, string message, string accept, 
string cancel){
 return await Page.DisplayAlert(title, message, accept, cancel);
}

// SomeMethod will run Synchronously
public boolean SomeMethod(){
  bool result = StaticClass.DisplayAlert(..).Result;
  return result;
}
```

EDIT: Fixed some syntax

Comment: Thanks, but this code will deadlock (((  use async all the way down seems illogical to me...

Comment: Not deadlock, it will wait syncronsly until DisplayAlert returns a result. That's not definition of a deadlock.

Comment: i tried but there is deadlock. [link](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html)

Comment: Alright ok, so why do you want `SomeMethod` to be sync ?

Comment: Where do you call this method

Comment: For example, ```SomeMethod``` is called into the button click. But you're right SomeMethod no need to be sync.

Comment: In the Mobile world you very rarely want syncronous calls, you should never block your UI in any case